# Grails 3.x and 2.5.x and java 11 compatibility issue

Tags: java, maven, gradle, grails, groovy

I have a project currently in grails 2.5.x and upgrading to grails 3.0.17.

Grails 2.5.x is being compiled on Java 11 (Didn't found any official Support).
Grails 3.0.17 when compiled(the same project after upgrading) give error that it doesnt support Java 11 (didn't got the logic why)

I found some pages where it says grails 3.0.17 uses gradle 2.4 and groovy 2.x which doesnt support Java 11 but makes no sense that it gets compiled on grails 2.5.x, a older version.

Comment: We can hardly help you with the requirements library authors set for
their libraries?  Use JDK8 and migrate to Grails 3, then to Grails 4,
then switch to JDK11?

Comment: "I found some pages where it says grails 3.0.17 uses gradle 2.4..." - By default I don't think that is true.   By default the Gradle wrapper for a Grails 3.0.17 app uses Gradle 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Grails 2, and 3 does not officially support Java 11. You need to update to Grails 4 to get Java 11 support.